# CDF Player and CloudObject`Private` Problem

Tags: manipulate, wolfram-cloud

I'm trying to generate a simple `Manipulate[]` example showing Taylor expansion. However, the following code shows `CloudObject'Private'x` instead of `x` in the cdf-Player preview:

```
ser[n_]:=Normal[Series[Sin[x],{x,Pi/2,n}]];

Manipulate[Plot[{Sin[x],Evaluate[ser[n]]},{x,-Pi,2Pi},
Frame->True, PlotLegends->"n="<>ToString[n],
PlotRange->{-1.5,1.5}, FrameLabel->{"x","sin(x)"}, 
LabelStyle->Directive[20],Frame->True,
PlotLabel->Style[Series[Sin[x],{x,\[Pi]/2,n}],Directive[10]] ],
{{n,4},Dynamic[Slider[#1,{0,4,2}]]&}]
```

How to fix this problem? I'm Using Mathematica V10.3.1

**EDIT**: I restarted the kernel. This resolved the `CloudObject` problem, *HOWEVER*, now the approximation curve is not showing up when doing the CDF preview or exporting to CDF after extending the manipulate by

```
ser[n_, x0_] := Normal[Series[Sin[x], {x, x0, n}]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Evaluate[ser[Floor[n], x0]]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> "n=" <> ToString[n], 
  PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, FrameLabel -> {x, "sin(x)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[20], Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, n}]],
 {{n, 1}, Dynamic[Slider[#1, {1, 7, 2}]] &}, {{x0, 0}, 
  Dynamic[Slider[#1, {-Pi, Pi}]] &}]
```

This has been now reproduced on my Debian and Ubuntu 16.4.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Could you describe more precisely what steps are  required to reproduce that problem?

Comment: @Kuba: I'm using Debian 3.14.5-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I go to File-> CDF Preview->CDF Player. All variables in the payer are combined with the CloudObject'Private' info. I also copied it in a new .nb file. This didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I could resolve the *CloudObject* problem by restarting the *mathkernel* and export the `Manipulate`-element once again.
- The problem with the missing approximation curve can be solved by not defining the function `ser[]` outside of `Manipulate[]`.

However, concerning the latter, I have no idea why no error message is returned.